# Use of past tense in situational present

Tags: past-tense

Is it idiomatic to say this.

> Some people can be grumpy especially if they didn’t have a good night sleep.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably put a comma after "grumpy", but yes, your sentence is correct and natural.

Edit: A "good night sleep" is ok, but a "a good night's sleep" is probably better.
Edit edit: A Google search says that "good night sleep" and "good night's sleep" are both very common, with "night" being more common. When spoken they sound almost identical, with the "s" blurring into the "s" in "sleep".

Comment: How about this? Some people after you helped them just go away. Or some people after you help them just go away.

Comment: The sentence is much more clear if you say "Some people just go away after you help them". If you want to phrase it in your order you need commas for clarity: "Some people, after you help them, just go away". Saying "after you help" or  "after you've helped" are definitely correct. I'm pretty sure that "after you helped" is also fine, it sounds fine to me, but there's a small corner of my mind wondering whether formal English teacher might complain. It's not something a native speaker would notice in conversation. The only issue is that you need to add commas or change the order for clarity.